# Function in django views run 2 times without reason

Tags: python, django

I have problem because I can not find the reason why my function in **Django** **views.py** sometimes runs two times. When I go to url, which call function create_db in Django view, function read json files from directory, parse it and write the data in the database. Most of the time it works perfectly, but sometimes for no reason it runs two times and write the same data in the data base. Does anyone know what can be the reason why code is sometimes done twice and how can I solve the problem?

Here is my create_db function:

```py
def create_db(request):
     response_data = {}
     try:
         start = time.time()
         files = os.listdir()
         print(files)
         for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.json'):
                print(filename)
                with open(f'{filename.strip()}', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                    data = json.load(f)
                    for item in data["CVE_Items"]:
                        import_item(item)
        response_data['result'] = 'Success'
        response_data['message'] = 'Baza podatkov je ustvarjena.'
    except KeyError:
        response_data['result'] = 'Error'
        response_data['message'] = 'Prislo je do napake! Podatki niso bili uvozeni!'

    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data), content_type='application/json')
```

The console output that I expect:

```
['nvdcve-1.0-2002.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2003.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2004.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2005.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2006.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2007.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2008.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2009.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2010.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2011.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2012.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2013.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2014.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2015.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2016.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2017.json']
nvdcve-1.0-2002.json
nvdcve-1.0-2003.json
nvdcve-1.0-2004.json
nvdcve-1.0-2005.json
nvdcve-1.0-2006.json
nvdcve-1.0-2007.json
nvdcve-1.0-2008.json
nvdcve-1.0-2009.json
nvdcve-1.0-2010.json
nvdcve-1.0-2011.json
nvdcve-1.0-2012.json
nvdcve-1.0-2013.json
nvdcve-1.0-2014.json
nvdcve-1.0-2015.json
nvdcve-1.0-2016.json
nvdcve-1.0-2017.json
```

Console output when error happened:

```
['nvdcve-1.0-2002.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2003.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2004.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2005.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2006.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2007.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2008.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2009.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2010.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2011.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2012.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2013.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2014.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2015.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2016.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2017.json']
nvdcve-1.0-2002.json
['nvdcve-1.0-2002.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2003.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2004.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2005.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2006.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2007.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2008.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2009.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2010.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2011.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2012.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2013.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2014.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2015.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2016.json', 'nvdcve-1.0-2017.json']
nvdcve-1.0-2002.json
nvdcve-1.0-2003.json
nvdcve-1.0-2003.json
nvdcve-1.0-2004.json
nvdcve-1.0-2004.json
nvdcve-1.0-2005.json
nvdcve-1.0-2005.json
nvdcve-1.0-2006.json
nvdcve-1.0-2006.json
nvdcve-1.0-2007.json
nvdcve-1.0-2007.json
nvdcve-1.0-2008.json
nvdcve-1.0-2008.json
nvdcve-1.0-2009.json
nvdcve-1.0-2009.json
nvdcve-1.0-2010.json
nvdcve-1.0-2010.json
nvdcve-1.0-2011.json
nvdcve-1.0-2011.json
nvdcve-1.0-2012.json
nvdcve-1.0-2012.json
nvdcve-1.0-2013.json
nvdcve-1.0-2013.json
nvdcve-1.0-2014.json
nvdcve-1.0-2014.json
nvdcve-1.0-2015.json
nvdcve-1.0-2015.json
nvdcve-1.0-2016.json
nvdcve-1.0-2016.json
nvdcve-1.0-2017.json
nvdcve-1.0-2017.json
```

Comment: can you show your csv

Comment: Which csv do you mean? @c.grey

Comment: is this a GET or POST request?

Comment: Where is this actually writing to the db? `import_item()`? And why do you say the function is running twice? What makes you think that? Is it possible `import_item` can write the data twice (you're running 2 for loops inside each other so `import_item` is running multiple times).

Comment: If this function is called through a web page, you'll have to create the exact circumstances that triggers `create_db` to be run twice. "Sometimes" can have many causes, and there is currently not enough information to find the cause, other than random guesswork. Once you've find the exact circumstances to trigger this issue, you can update your question with that information (but by that time, you may have found and fixed the problem yourself already).

Comment: When you say the function runs "two times", do you see the result of `print(files)` two times? Or just two updates in the database?

Comment: A update the questions with the console output. When the error occurs, duplicate data is in the database. @9769953

Comment: That looks like a double http request incoming. Check that it's not possible to double click your form or whatever you are using, and that the page is not reloaded and sending the data again by accident.

Comment: That's exactly what happened, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the code which you show us. Enable logging for the HTTP requests which your application receives to make sure the browser sends you just a single request. If you see two requests, make sure they use the same session (maybe another user is clicking at the same time).

If it's from the same user, maybe you're clicking the button twice. Could be a hardware problem with the mouse. To prevent this, use JavaScript to disable the button after the first click.